# Объясните, что такое CGI?

Tags: терминология, cgi

Что такое CGI? С вики статью прочитал ничего не понял. И что значит PHP установлен как CGI?

Comment: Апач ? КОгда же он помрет ? :) Ужасный веб-сервер. **php-fpm** используйте. *чтобы знать. (с)*

Comment: Апачь не сдохнет пока есть хостеры.

ставить php-frm можно, но опять же в вопросе нет ничего про сервер, но мы всегда догадываемся про апач.

Да круче поставить nginx, настроить его, но все это дело нужно тестировать. Прирост в производительности ухода php как от модуля, бывает дает всего 5%, что низко и заморачиваться бессмысленно. Причем прирост может быть на тестовом проекте, а на реальном сайте прирост будет в разы меньше, доказано практикой. т.к. в некоторых вещах все работает не так как нам хочется.

Предлагать варианты можно долго, тестируют варианты обычно единицы из 1000, так что ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> И что значит PHP установлен как CGI?

Это значит что хостинг не может сделать нормальную настройку php и привязать её к апачу.
в каждом скрипте придется указывать

```
   #!/usr/local/bin/php
```

чтобы все это безобразие заработало.

Лучше привязка php к апачу как модуль. [тут](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/install.general.php) почитать немного

И что [тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGI) непонятно написано?

Последний вопрос, зачем тебе это нужно если ты не понимаешь этого? Просто ради "Чтобы знать!" или есть какие-то еще варианты?

Comment: чтобы знать.

Comment: ок, чтобы знать :)

Answer (score 6):

Вообще-то CGI означает технологию, которая позволяет веб-серверу взаимодействовать с обычными исполняемыми программами и скриптами, которые пишутся практически на любом языке программирования.

Т.е. к примеру, если какой-нибудь Вася не знает ни `PHP` ни `ASP`, но отлично знает `C++` или `Pascal` и хоть немного разбирается в `HTML`, он может сделать программу, которая будет генерировать свой **динамический сайт** в консоль. Веб-сервер, при запросе этого сайта, выполняет эту программу, а результат ее работы (вывод консоли) возвращает клиенту, который его запросил.

Именно об этом и говорит предупреждение

> PHP установлен как CGI

т.е. при запросе любой PHP-странички, веб-сервер будет выполнять программу php, вместо того, чтобы передать управление модулю PHP.

т.е. на каждую страничку веб-сервер будет создавать новый процесс. Не все системы оптимизированы под такое взаимодействие программ, поэтому принято считать такой способ дорогим.